# Change the view background when an item from a ListView is activated/selected

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-listfragment

I'm going to explain (or at least try that) what I want to achieve because this is driving me crazy.

I have a ListView and the items have the following layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/item_background"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" >

        ... some contents here...

    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

"item_background.xml" contains a selector so the background changes depending on the item's state. It's working fine when I press and release the item but it's not working when I 'select' the item with a DPAD/Trackball. I have tried everything (state_activated, state_focused, state_selected...) but nothing works. I'm trying to search for a solution but looks like I can't find the proper keywords to search for.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to set the background (item_background) to root FrameLayout of your layout(which has the 10dp padding)?

Comment: I can try that just to be sure that it works there. I'll do it asap.

Comment: I just tried that and it's not working too. Now I'm very confused.

Comment: I just did another test. In my ListView I'm using '@color/transparent' for the list selector (I don't want the entire item to become blue when I select/press it, I want full control). I just set the default selector to do some testing and that works perfectly, but the FrameLayout background is still not changing (even if I put it in the root FrameLayout). I guess I'll have to make it work using a custom list selector.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I fixed it. The problem was in the order I put the items inside the selector (I put a state_pressed="false" before the state_selected="true").

Now it works flawlessly.

Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This does most likely not work because some layout above your root layout gets the focus (hard to tell without the rest of the layout).

Comment: Currently I'm doing the tests with the layout I posted above but without any contents inside.